# Projective Transformations in GR

Tags: general-relativity

A Thought Experiment:

We are in flat spaceime provided with a reference frame—a rectangular Cartesian frame. The coordinate labels[the spatial labels] are visible to us. Each spatial point is provided with a clock—and the different clocks are synchronized wrt to each other. Gravity is now turned on and made to  vary upto some final state. During this process of experimentation the physical separations change while the coordinate labels remain fixed to their own positions. [Coordinate separations remain unchanged]. The length and the orientation of a vector changes in this process both in the 3D and in the 4D sense. We are passing through different/distinct manifolds in our thought experiment and if  the  4D arc length does not change we are simply having a transition between manifolds for which ds^2 is not changing but the metric coefficients are changing.We consider the option of $ds^2$ changing in this posting.

Query:
Our experiment indicates at projective transformations operating  in the physical sense[considering changes in the metric and in the value $ds^2$].A time dependent field is being observed where the metric coefficients are not being  preserved. Is it important to include projective transformations[concerned with the non-preservation of the metric] in the mathematical framework of GR?

Comment: You aren't talking about what are normally called "projective transformations", you are talking about dynamical coordinate transformations. This is called the "hole argument" in the early GR literature, and in some obnoxiously wrongheaded current philosophy literature.

Answer (score 1):

What you are talking about are not what are normally called projective transformations, but nonphysical coordinate changes, these are gauge changes in GR. Einstein was famously confused about this for years, beginning in 1913 when he wrote about the "Hole Argument" in General Relativity. He concluded that it is impossible to have generally covariant equations of motion, only changing his mind in 1915 when he realized the hole argument was completely bogus.

The hole argument is similar to your "projective transformations". He imagines a manifold where the physical situation stays the same, but the points get relabelled dynamically. This leads the metric coefficients to change in a certain way, which cannot be determined by the equation of motion, because it is totally arbitrary.

You didn't say it exactly the same--- you considered letting the metric coefficients change with time, so that the coordinate distance changes, but at the end of the day, the length of any two curves stays the same with the appropriate map, so that the transformation is just a coordinate change. So it's the same thing.

To get unconfused about this, it is best to think of the exactly analogous (but much simpler) gauge transformations in EM. Two vector potentials which have the same holonomy (the same E and B fields in spacetime of normal trivial topology) are identified. This identification means that oscillations of the electromagnetic potential of the form $A=\nabla \phi$ are unphysical, and they have no specific heat, they don't move charges, etc.

The coordinate transformations in GR are exactly analogous. They are more interesting, because in GR, unlike in EM, a gauge transformation, a coordinate change, can introduce a horizon where there was none before. This happens when you change coordinates to the frame of a constantly accelerated observer.

Comment: In the suggested experiment[referring to the question] the coordinate labels remain fixed in their own locations.I have clearly stated that the coordinate separations remain unchanged but the physical separations change due to changes in the values of $g_{\mu\nu}$,coordinate labels remaining fixed in their own positions. *The points have not been relabelled in any way--but physical separations have changed*

Comment: @AnamitraPalit: But you said a few sentences later that "ds does not change". What ds doesn't change? You either mean that you are doing a shift of metric which is not physical, or you are saying self-contradictory things.

Comment: I have simply said that *if ds^2 does not change* while the transition[change in the values of $g_{\mu\nu}$] is going on,there would be a serious problem----there would be a physical transition between distinct manifolds where the metric is not being preserved[due to changes in $g_{\mu\nu}$] while the value of the line element remains invariant.In such an event we would have a corresponding mathematical transformation from one manifold to another where the metric is not preserved while $ds^2$ is preserved.So ds^2 should change in these transformations.That is exactly what I wanted to say.

Comment: @AnamitraPalit: Is it possible to describe your scenario as "a diffeomorphism from the active viewpoint (points move around, but labels move with them) that is not an isometry ($ds^2$ changes)" ?  This would probably be more conventional terminology than "projective transformations", which is more often used in connection with projective geometry.

Comment: @Anamitra: If you aren't talking about hole argument, I don't see what you are talking about at all. So you can change the metric on a manifold to get a different metric manifold. Who cares? How is this a problem? You can continuously deform a metric sphere to a metric egg or a metric box. Why is this a contradiction?

Comment: Let's consider the definition of a cntravariant tensor:$T'^{\mu\nu}=\frac{\partial x'^{\mu}}{\partial x^\alpha}\frac{\partial x'^{\nu}}{\partial x^\beta}T^{\alpha\beta}$. Such a definitition assumes relations like $x'^\mu=x'^\mu(x^\alpha,x^\beta)$ and $x'^\nu=x'^\nu(x^\alpha,x^\beta)$ . $ds^2$ does not change in these relations. The above definition of tensors is valid only in a particular type of manifold where the line element is invariant in value.Then how do you define tensors if different /distinct manifolds are in consideration?What about tensor equations retaining their form?

Comment: @Anamitra: The tensor transformation law is only for coordinate changes of one fixed manifold. Once you have a tensor field on the manifold, you do a coordinate transformation, you get the form of the new representation of the same tensor. The transformed tensors are to be physically identified with each other, they form one mathematical object, the abstract tensor field on the abstract manifold (the mathematician would say, the section of the appropriate tensor bundle). The transformations, by design, don't go from one manifold to another one.

Comment: What about the tensor equations retaining their form in different/distinct manifolds?The geodesic equation,Maxwell's equations[in covariant form] have the same form in all manifolds. As we change/vary the field in our experiment are these laws are not supposed to change.What is the theory behind such universal application of the laws?

Comment: @AnamitraPalit: I'm not sure there is any theory behind the universality, other than the fact physics obeys laws.  Maxwell's equations on Minkowski spacetime have the same form as Maxwell's equations on, say de Sitter spacetime. To illustrate what Ron said, the subject of those equations, the potential, is a one form $A_{\mu}dx^{\mu}$ which itself "lives" over the manifold and represents a coord. indep. object, but its components $A_{\mu}$ are coordinate dependent.  However, a Maxwell potential on Minkowski space is a different object to one on de Sitter space.  They live in different bundles.

Comment: @twistor59: While mathematically you are right, Anamitra Palit has a valid point--- there is a sense and meaning we can give to the statement that the same equations hold on different manifolds. This sense can be understood somehow as "varying the metric from one manifold to another", and then the equations are somehow preserved. But this idea is not in my answer, and is not normally discussed. I think it is interesting question, what does it mean for two local equations on different manifolds to be the "same equation"?

Comment: @RonMaimon: I must admit I'm not sure how to say it properly.  The equations I guess are defined globally by a lagrangian function on some jet bundle of the appropriate vector bundle.  We'd need some sort of category theoretic way of formulating an equivalence of two manifold/bundle/lagrangian systems which encapsulated that the two sets of equations were the same, not just locally, patchwise, but globally too ?

Comment: We start with flat spacetime. A particle moves with uniform speed along a straight line: we consider the points a1,a2,a3..an on it for our convenience.When gravity is turned on not only the relative physical separations between consecutive $a_i$ change but the separation of $a_i$ from other surrounding points[you may consider points on lines parallel to the line of motion in flat spacetime] change. These changes are by different amounts. So the straight line in Minkowski space becomes a curved line.We are supposed to get a parabola in Schwarzschild's Geometry.

Comment: Projective transformations can provide us with a convenient workspace if we assume that the laws of Physics are same[identical in form] on all manifolds.Suoppose we are working out a problem in curved spacetime.We turn off gravity and perform our calculations in flat space. If we *assume* that the laws[relationships between the variables] are preserved, we can draw our conclusions in flat space. More important is that we can always go back to curved space by using the reverse transformations[projective] and obtain direct conclusions

Answer (score 0):

Interesting discussion.
This is my 2 cents contribution:

1- as @RonMaimon stated above, the term "projective transformations" is probably inappropriate and misleading in this context. "Projective" has specific meanings in mathematics, none of which seems to me to be applicable in this case. The OP should perhaps justify the use of the term

2- In GR literature there are examples of the kind of transformations described by the OP, where you have a parametrized family of manifolds *M($\epsilon$)* with metrics *g($\epsilon$)*  that are related by a $\epsilon$-family of isomorphisms. These transformations are used in (higher order) perturbative GR to covariantly describe perturbations of exact solutions.

For example see: http://arxiv.org/PS_cache/gr-qc/pdf/0607/0607025v1.pdf
or other papers by David Brizuela and Jose M. Martın-Garcıa

The conclusion is that the language of differential geometry is powerful enough to deal with these kinds of transformations which describe perturbations of the underlying manifold.